# Moving +1/+1's via Combine Guildmage

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So if I have [Kumena's Speaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKumena%27s%5d%2b%5bSpeaker%5d) on the battlefield with a +1/+1 due to his ability and a [Combine Guildmage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCombine%20Guildmage%5d) that can move +1/+1 from one creature to another. Does CG duplicate the +1/+1, and does KS get another +1/+1 due to having an island on the field or another merfolk

Comment: CG moves *counters*, and KS doesn't grant any *counters*

Comment: Hopefully the linked duplicate is clear. Guildmage cannot do anything with Kumena’s +1/+1, because it is not a counter.